# Why it's more difficult to walk in an inclined plane than in a causal road

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity, biophysics

my question is about something very casual , but when i tried to solve that , it was not easy at all . My question is : "Why when we walk in an inclined plane we get tired more than when we walk in casual road, when angle = 0 . This question came to me when i was  climbed up. I know that is something about angle and friction force but i cant solve this . I need your help .

Comment: because $U=mgh$?

Comment: Are you talking about walking up a hill?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each step in walking;

On a horizontal road: $F=ma$

And on an inclined road: $F-mg\sin\theta=ma$

So you need more power (greater $F$) when you are walking up a hill. It may be useful that we know maximum force $F$ we can use when we are walking is the limiting friction force.
Figure below shows free body diagram for walking on a horizontal road.

[image]

Comment: so you are saying that friction force has no influence when we are walking ?

Comment: Force that causes our motion is the friction force. If we plot free body diagram of us, we can see this.

Comment: In a horizontal road: F_f=ma
And in an inclined road: F_f-mgsinθ=ma
That F_f is friction force and equal to our force F (third law of newton).

Comment: So, F=f ,and this is real when we are not moving but we are moving so f is not equal with F ,, I agree that F>f and both against each other because we are climbing up but not F=f ,

Comment: can you send me a figure and equation to ilustrate ?